# SQL Server: How substract rows of one column from rows of another table's column

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables A and B:

- A has id, ColumnA
- B has id, ColumnB

A looks like:

```
id  ColumnA
-----------
1   A1
5   A5
7   A7
```

B looks like:

```
id  ColumnB
-----------
1   B1
3   B3
5   B5
8   B8
```

I want result like table B i.e. (id, ColumnB) that should be values that are in table B but not in table A.

So, result should look like:

```
Id  ColumnB
-----------
3   B3
8   B8
```

How can I do this efficiently?

I tried using taking left join and inner join and then subtracting but I think it can be done in a better way.. Suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `NOT EXISTS` predicate

```
SELECT * FROM B WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM A WHERE A.ID = B.ID)
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `NOT EXISTS` to do this

```
select id, ColumnB 
from tableB B
where not exists (select 1 from tableA A where B.Id = A.Id)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * 
FROM B 
WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM A)
```

Looking at the two tables you described, `id` doesn't seem to be nullable in either table, so the above query will work. You should however exercise caution with `IN` in situations where the sub-query could return `NULL` values.

Comment: May not handle `NULL` values well

Comment: @Prdp: Not sure what you're suggesting. An example might help.

Comment: `NOT IN` will fail when your `sub-query` returns any `NULL` values

Comment: @Prdp: mmm... Looking at the tables OP described, `id` of either table doesn't seem to be nullable.

Comment: You're both right, it looks like it will work on this case, but you should point out the `NULL` issues with `IN()` statement, because he may use this in the future for different purposes.

Comment: @sagi: Point taken. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you use a left join, you can filter out the values that are in table A in your where clause, i.e.

```
select *
from A
left join B on A.Id = B.Id
where A.Id is null
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * From B
    Where Not Exists (Select null From A Where A.ID = B.ID)
```